# Issue with LDAP for retrieving room list for exchange 2007

Tags: c#, ldap, directoryservices, exchange-server-2007

I am trying to find all Meeting rooms for Exchange Server 2007 using c#. I found an easy way to do this by using EWS Managed API:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/hh532566(v=exchg.80).aspx

Unfortunately, GetRoomLists() does not work for Exchange Server 2007. I am hoping if some has worked or know how can I find meeting rooms on exchange server 2007, that would be a great help. I want to see all the meeting room available on Exchange server and then want to use their properties.

Is there a way I can show all the existing room and then use its properties like Phone/Notes tab information?

I was working with LDAP but it keeps giving me error "The server is not operational". I thought may be I am using wrong credential. Therefore I tried with Google and it did not help me.

Enclosed please find my code:-

```
        using (DirectoryEntry dir2 = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://www.google.com/DC=www,DC=google,DC=com", null, null,  AuthenticationTypes.Encryption))
        {
           dir2.RefreshCache();

            DirectorySearcher adSearch = new DirectorySearcher(dir2);
            adSearch.Filter = "(&(objectClass=*)(msExchRecipientDisplayType=7))";
            SearchResultCollection adResult = adSearch.FindAll();

            foreach (SearchResult item in adResult)
            {

                ResultPropertyCollection property = item.Properties;

                ResultPropertyValueCollection name = property["name"];
                ResultPropertyValueCollection proxyAddresses = property["proxyAddresses"];
                ResultPropertyValueCollection legacyExchangeDN = property["legacyExchangeDN"];

                ..........
        }
}
```

It gives me error on enclosed code :-
`dir2.RefreshCache();` 
I am not sure, what I am doing wrong. I have tried with different LDAP values like :-
`using (DirectoryEntry dir2 = new  DirectoryEntry("LDAP://ldap.google.com/DC=www,DC=google,DC=com", null, null, AuthenticationTypes.Encryption))`

`using (DirectoryEntry dir2 = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP:///DC=www,DC=google,DC=com", null, null, AuthenticationTypes.Encryption))`

`using (DirectoryEntry dir2 = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://DC=www,DC=google,DC=com", null, null, AuthenticationTypes.Encryption))`

But nothing really helped me.

Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Enclosed please find the stack trace:

```
 at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.RefreshCache()
   at Test_Exchange.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\Test Exchange\Test Exchange\Program.cs:line 26
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: If your computer is joined to the domain, you should be able to just do DirectoryEntry dir2 = new DirectoryEntry().  Does that work?

Answer (score 0):

I thought to share what I did wrong. It may help others.
It is working well now. The issue was wrong AD name.
Please check with IT or administrator to confirm if you are using correct Active Directory name.

Cheers!!

Comment: FYI, on StackOverflow you're expected to mark the answer that solved your problem as Accepted by clicking on the checkmark next to that answer.  People are much less inclined to answer questions from people that don't do this.